# Splitting lists by short numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, split

I'm using NumPy to find intersections on a graph, but `isClose` returns multiple values per intersection

So, I'm going to try to find their averages. But first, I want to isolate the similar values. This is also a useful skill I feel.

I have a list of the x values for the intersection called `idx` that looks like this

```
[-8.67735471 -8.63727455 -8.59719439 -5.5511022  -5.51102204 -5.47094188
 -5.43086172 -2.4248497  -2.38476954 -2.34468938 -2.30460922  0.74148297
  0.78156313  0.82164329  3.86773547  3.90781563  3.94789579  3.98797595
  7.03406814  7.0741483   7.11422846]
```

and I want to separate it out into lists each comprised of the similar numbers.

this is what I have so far:

```
n = 0
for i in range(len(idx)):
    try:
        if (idx[n]-idx[n-1])<0.5:
            sdx.append(idx[n-1])
        else:
            print(sdx)
            sdx = []
    except:
        sdx.append(idx[n-1])
    n = n+1
```

It works for the most part but it forgets some numbers:

```
[-8.6773547094188377, -8.6372745490981959]
[-5.5511022044088181, -5.5110220440881763, -5.4709418837675354]
[-2.4248496993987976, -2.3847695390781567, -2.3446893787575149]
[0.7414829659318638, 0.78156312625250379]
[3.8677354709418825, 3.9078156312625243, 3.9478957915831661]
```

Theres probably a more efficient way to do this, does anyone know of one?

Comment: What is the end use of this?  Are you making a histogram?  What determines the groupings -- is it just they are within 0.5 of each other?   What would you expect to happen on [-0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]?

Comment: Please describe what this is supposed to do. Guessing it from non-functioning code is not an option. And where are all the commas that your idx is missing?

Comment: is that a numpy array?

Comment: Why are you looping with `for i in range(len(idx)):` and then using `n` (which you have to manually increment) for indexing the list?

Comment: What is `n` initially set to?

Comment: I edited to the question to answer some of these, sorry. Also `idx` is a numpy array, thats probably why it has no commas.

Comment: You forgot to answer the most important question(s)... nobody knows what you mean with "short" or "similar".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering you have a numpy array, you can use [np.split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html), splitting where the difference is > `.5`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-8.67735471, -8.63727455, -8.59719439, -5.5511022, -5.51102204, -5.47094188,
     -5.43086172, -2.4248497, -2.38476954, -2.34468938, -2.30460922, 0.74148297,
     0.78156313, 0.82164329, 3.86773547, 3.90781563, 3.94789579, 3.98797595,
     7.03406814, 7.0741483])


print np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x) > .5)[0] + 1)

[array([-8.67735471, -8.63727455, -8.59719439]), array([-5.5511022 , -5.51102204, -5.47094188, -5.43086172]), array([-2.4248497 , -2.38476954, -2.34468938, -2.30460922]), array([ 0.74148297,  0.78156313,  0.82164329]), array([ 3.86773547,  3.90781563,  3.94789579,  3.98797595]), array([ 7.03406814,  7.0741483 ])]
```

`np.where(np.diff(x) > .5)[0]` returns the index where the following element does not meet the `np.diff(x) > .5)` condition:

```
In [6]: np.where(np.diff(x) > .5)[0]
Out[6]: array([ 2,  6, 10, 13, 17])
```

`+ 1` adds 1 to each index:

```
In [12]: np.where(np.diff(x) > .5)[0] + 1
Out[12]: array([ 3,  7, 11, 14, 18])
```

Then passing `[ 3,  7, 11, 14, 18]` to np.split splits the elements into subarrays, `x[:3], x[3:7],x[7:11] ...`

Answer (score 0):

If your *final destination* is finding average values of each cluster/group, where each cluster would be marked by little difference that don't cross a certain threshold, you can use the approach listed next.

Basically, we convert the input list to a numpy array, sort it and then find consecutive differences. Based on the differences when compared against a certain threshold, we create a ID array with same IDs for elements from the same group. Finally, using those IDs, we do binning and averaging within the bins with [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), essentially getting the average of each group.

Here's the implementation -

```
import numpy as np

# Input list
AList = [-8.67735471, -8.63727455, -8.59719439, -5.5511022,  -5.51102204,
         -5.47094188, -5.43086172, -2.4248497,  -2.38476954, -2.34468938,
         -2.30460922,  0.74148297,  0.78156313,  0.82164329,  3.86773547,
    3.90781563, 3.94789579,  3.98797595,  7.03406814,  7.0741483, 7.11422846]

# Tolerance as thresholding parameter to distinguish between two "groups"
tolerance = 1

# Convert to a numpy array and sort if not already sorted
A = np.sort(np.asarray(AList))

# ID array that has the same IDs for elements of the same group
ID_array = (np.append([False],np.diff(A)>tolerance)).cumsum()

# Finally get the average values for each group    
average_values = np.bincount(ID_array,A)/np.bincount(ID_array)
```

Sample run -

```
In [301]: A
Out[301]: 
array([-8.67735471, -8.63727455, -8.59719439, -5.5511022 , -5.51102204,
       -5.47094188, -5.43086172, -2.4248497 , -2.38476954, -2.34468938,
       -2.30460922,  0.74148297,  0.78156313,  0.82164329,  3.86773547,
        3.90781563,  3.94789579,  3.98797595,  7.03406814,  7.0741483 ,
        7.11422846])

In [302]: average_values
Out[302]: 
array([-8.63727455, -5.49098196, -2.36472946,  0.78156313,  3.92785571,
        7.0741483 ])
```