# Finding groups of increasing numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools, iterable

**The aim is to find groups of increasing/monotonic numbers given a list of integers. Each item in the resulting group must be of a +1 increment from the previous item**

Given an input:

```
x = [7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need to find groups of increasing numbers and achieve:

```
increasing_numbers = [(7,8,9,10), (0,1,2,3,4,5)]
```

And eventually also the number of increasing numbers:

```
len(list(chain(*increasing_numbers)))
```

And also the len of the groups:

```
increasing_num_groups_length = [len(i) for i in increasing_numbers]
```

I have tried the following to get the number of increasing numbers:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, chain
>>> def pairwise(iterable): 
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)
... 
>>> x = [8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> set(list(chain(*[(i,j) for i,j in pairwise(x) if j-1==i])))
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11])
>>> len(set(list(chain(*[(i,j) for i,j in pairwise(x) if j-1==i]))))
10
```

But I'm unable to keep the order and the groups of increasing numbers.

**How can I achieve the `increasing_numbers` groups of integer tuples and also the `increasing_num_groups_length`?**

**Also, is there a name for such/similar problem?**

---

## EDITED

I've came up with this solution but it's super verbose and I'm sure there's an easier way to achieve the `increasing_numbers` output:

```
>>> from itertools import tee, chain
>>> def pairwise(iterable): 
...     a, b = tee(iterable)
...     next(b, None)
...     return zip(a, b)
... 
>>> x = [8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> boundary =  iter([0] + [i+1 for i, (j,k) in enumerate(pairwise(x)) if j+1!=k] + [len(x)])
>>> [tuple(x[i:next(boundary)]) for i in boundary]
[(8, 9, 10, 11), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

**Is there a more pythonic / less verbose way to do this?**

---

Another input/output example:

[in]:

> [17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
>   14, 14, 14, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40]

[out]:

> [(19, 20, 21, 22), (0, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
>   (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36)]

Comment: It would call your problem: finding intervals on which data is monotonous and increasing. It is actually as simple as finding the places where the data is **not** increasing, and using it as the boundaries for your groups  (assuming that the data is never decreasing, but that seemed to be the case from both your description and your input).

Comment: My solution looks like some monster perl script =( Is there someone who knows a pythonic solution to this? BTW, this is not homework, just trying to get part of an algorithm right. And it requires this "monotonic" or increasing sequence counting.

Comment: When pythonic becomes cryptic, I usually opt for a simple for loop.

Comment: @alvas. Your output seems to be wrong, since the second sequence begins `0, 1, 2, 2, ...`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, whoops, human blindness. Yep, it should start at `4...` instead.

Comment: @alvas. This is starting to become pretty funny: now you missed `0, 1, 2` as the second sequence. Maybe you should use one of the answers to check your question is right ;-)

Comment: Thank you all for the interesting solutions, if it's alright, i've given the bounty to the @ekhumoro answer and for completion pandaric's answer seems to be best =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of different ways using itertools and numpy:

```
from itertools import groupby, tee, cycle

x = [17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
     36, 1, 2, 3, 4,34,54]


def sequences(l):
    x2 = cycle(l)
    next(x2)
    grps = groupby(l, key=lambda j: j + 1 == next(x2))
    for k, v in grps:
        if k:
            yield tuple(v) + (next((next(grps)[1])),)


print(list(sequences(x)))

[(19, 20, 21, 22), (0, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Or using python3 and yield from:

```
def sequences(l):
    x2 = cycle(l)
    next(x2)
    grps = groupby(l, key=lambda j: j + 1 == next(x2))
    yield from (tuple(v) + (next((next(grps)[1])),) for k,v in grps if k)

print(list(sequences(x)))
```

Using a variation of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241068/splitting-lists-by-short-numbers/30241768#30241768) with numpy.split :

```
out = [tuple(arr) for arr in np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x) != 1)[0] + 1) if arr.size > 1]

print(out)

[(19, 20, 21, 22), (0, 1, 2), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

And similar to ekhumoro's answer:

```
def sequences(x):
    it = iter(x)
    prev, temp = next(it), []
    while prev is not None:
        start = next(it, None)
        if prev + 1 == start:
            temp.append(prev)
        elif temp:
            yield tuple(temp + [prev])
            temp = []
        prev = start
```

To get the length and the tuple:

```
def sequences(l):
    x2 = cycle(l)
    next(x2)
    grps = groupby(l, key=lambda j: j + 1 == next(x2))
    for k, v in grps:
        if k:
            t = tuple(v) + (next(next(grps)[1]),)
            yield t, len(t)


def sequences(l):
    x2 = cycle(l)
    next(x2)
    grps = groupby(l, lambda j: j + 1 == next(x2))
    yield from ((t, len(t)) for t in (tuple(v) + (next(next(grps)[1]),)
                                      for k, v in grps if k))



def sequences(x):
        it = iter(x)
        prev, temp = next(it), []
        while prev is not None:
            start = next(it, None)
            if prev + 1 == start:
                temp.append(prev)
            elif temp:
                yield tuple(temp + [prev]), len(temp) + 1
                temp = []
            prev = start
```

Output will be the same for all three:

```
[((19, 20, 21, 22), 4), ((0, 1, 2), 3), ((4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), 11)
, ((28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36), 9), ((1, 2, 3, 4), 4)]
```

Comment: The numpy solution looks interesting. Could you help explain the numpy method a little? The `np.diff` and `np.where` and `np.split` gets a little cryptic ;P

Comment: @alvas, I added a link to an old answer of mine, the logic is basically the same

Comment: Thanks!! That helps a lot =)

Comment: No prob, do you also want to group the length of each tuple in the output?

Comment: Ultimately, both the groups and the lengths would be useful but given the groups, it shouldn't be hard to reloop through to get the length. Do you have a solution to keep the complexity without relooping?

Comment: You could get it all in one loop quite easily as long as you don't mind getting the count last. What kind of format would you want it in?

Comment: I guess it's easiest way is to do a `[ [((sequence), int(len))], [((sequence), int(len))], ... ]`

Comment: @alvas,  have a look at the edits and see if we are on the same page

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks Padraic!

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**:

Here's a code-golf solution (142 characters):

```
def f(x):s=[0]+[i for i in range(1,len(x)) if x[i]!=x[i-1]+1]+[len(x)];return [x[j:k] for j,k in [s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)] if k-j>1]
```

Expanded version:

```
def igroups(x):
    s = [0] + [i for i in range(1, len(x)) if x[i] != x[i-1] + 1] + [len(x)]
    return [x[j:k] for j, k in [s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)] if k - j > 1]
```

Commented version:

```
def igroups(x):
    # find the boundaries where numbers are not consecutive
    boundaries = [i for i in range(1, len(x)) if x[i] != x[i-1] + 1]
    # add the start and end boundaries
    boundaries = [0] + boundaries + [len(x)]
    # take the boundaries as pairwise slices
    slices = [boundaries[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(boundaries) - 1)]
    # extract all sequences with length greater than one
    return [x[start:end] for start, end in slices if end - start > 1]
```

**Original solution**:

Not sure whether this counts as "pythonic" or "not too verbose":

```
def igroups(iterable):
    items = iter(iterable)
    a, b = None, next(items, None)
    result = [b]
    while b is not None:
        a, b = b, next(items, None)
        if b is not None and a + 1 == b:
            result.append(b)
        else:
            if len(result) > 1:
                yield tuple(result)
            result = [b]

print(list(igroups([])))
print(list(igroups([0, 0, 0])))
print(list(igroups([7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
print(list(igroups([8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])))
print(list(igroups([9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5])))
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[(7, 8, 9, 10), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
[(8, 9, 10, 11), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's looks more "readable" for sure. But maybe there's a simpler way. It's not as simple as the people who downvoted this question thought, right?

Comment: @ekhumoro: Last output, ultimate 5 is missing, isn't it?

Comment: @P.Ortiz. No: I'm assuming from the OPs own solution (`if j+1!=k`) that they only want sequences with no gaps (i.e. always increasing by one). If that's not the case, though, the test can just be changed to `a < b`.

Comment: @alvas. I'm not exactly sure why your question received so many downvotes. Maybe because the requirements not very well defined, and you don't say what *specific* problems you are having in trying to find a solution. And what *exactly* would count as a "simpler way"? I hope you don't just mean "shorter", because that would be off-topic for SO. If you want shorter, ask on [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Surely not shorter. Simply as in easier to understand and hopefully more pythonic, possibly similar to what you have done. The problem is simply to group increasing numbers in a list =)

Comment: @alvas. Is the problem so simple? Look carefully at the tests in my answer: do they all give the results you expect? When I try them with your own solution, the second gives `[(0,), (0,)]` and the last gives `[(9,), (1,), (5,)]`. To be more specific: should the sequences **only** increase by one (i.e. no gaps), and does a one-item sequence count?

Comment: The sequence should only increase by +1

Comment: @ekhumoro: you are right, I didn't realize that integers has to be *consecutive*.

Comment: You can get that down to 135 bytes `def f(x):q=len(x);s=[0]+[i for i in range(1,q)if x[i]!=x[i-1]+1]+[q];return[x[j:k]for j,k in[s[i:i+2]for i in range(len(s)-1)]if k-j>1]`

Answer (score 3):

I think the most maintainable solution would be to make it simple:

```
def group_by(l):
    res = [[l[0]]]
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        if l[i-1] < l[i]:
            res[-1].append(l[i])
        else:
            res.append([l[i]])
    return res
```

This solution does not filter out single element sequences, but it can be easily implemented. Additionally, this has O(n) complexity. And you can make it an generator as well if you want.

By maintainable I mean code that is not an one-liner of 300 characters, with some convoluted expressions. Then maybe you would want to use Perl :). At least you will how the function behaves one year later.

```
>>> x = [7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(group_by(x))
[[7, 8, 9, 10], [6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def igroups(L):
    R=[[]]
    [R[-1].append(L[i]) for i in range(len(L)) if (L[i-1]+1==L[i] if L[i-1]+1==L[i] else R.append([L[i]]))]
    return [P for P in R if len(P)>1]


tests=[[],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5],
    [4,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,4,3],
    [1, 4, 3],
    [1],
    [1,2],
    [2,1]
    ]
for L in tests:
    print(L)
    print(igroups(L))
    print("-"*10)
```

outputting the following:

```
[]
[]
----------
[0, 0, 0]
[]
----------
[7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[[7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
----------
[8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[[8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
----------
[9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
----------
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
----------
[1, 4, 3]
[]
----------
[1]
[]
----------
[1, 2]
[[1, 2]]
----------
[2, 1]
[]
----------
```

EDIT
My first attemp using `itertools.groupby` was a fail, sorry for that.

Comment: Lolz, understandable but scarily cryptic. Care to explain the answer a little? ;P

Comment: As explained by the Python library docs,  `groupby` generates a new group every time the value of the lambda function changes (from `True` meaning that the sequence is increasing to `False` meaning the sequence halts increasing).

Comment: @P.Ortiz. Your current code looks like it is broken because it outputs: `[[7, 8, 9], [10, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`.

Comment: My error and apologies; I was on the wrong question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If two consecutive numbers are increasing by one I form a `list` (`group`) of `tuples` of those numbers.

When non-increasing and if the `list` (`group`) is non-empty, I unpack it and `zip` again to rebuild the pair of sequence which were broken by the `zip`. I use `set` comprehension to eliminate duplicate numbers.

```
  def extract_increasing_groups(seq):
    seq = tuple(seq)

    def is_increasing(a,b):
        return a + 1 == b

    def unzip(seq):
        return tuple(sorted({ y for x in zip(*seq) for y in x}))

    group = []
    for a,b in zip(seq[:-1],seq[1:]):
        if is_increasing(a,b):
            group.append((a,b))
        elif group:
            yield unzip(group)
            group = []

    if group:
        yield unzip(group)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = [17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,

         13, 14, 14, 14, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40]

    for group in extract_increasing_groups(x):
        print(group)
```

Simpler one using set;

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import islice, tee

def extract_increasing_groups(iterable):

    iter1, iter2 = tee(iterable)
    iter2 = islice(iter2,1,None)

    is_increasing = lambda a,b: a + 1 == b
    Igroup = namedtuple('Igroup','group, len')

    group = set()
    for pair in zip(iter1, iter2):
        if is_increasing(*pair):
            group.update(pair)
        elif group:
            yield Igroup(tuple(sorted(group)),len(group))
            group = set()

    if group:
        yield Igroup(tuple(sorted(group)), len(group))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = [17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 40]
    total = 0
    for group in extract_increasing_groups(x):
        total += group.len
        print('Group: {}\nLength: {}'.format(group.group, group.len))
    print('Total: {}'.format(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.groupby`, the problem of partionning a list of integers `L` in sublists of adjacent and increasing consecutive items from `L` can be done with a one-liner. Nevertheless I don't know how pythonic it can be considered ;)

Here is the code with some simple tests:

[EDIT : now subsequences are increasing **by 1**, I missed this point the first time.]

```
from itertools import groupby

def f(i):
    return  L[i-1]+1==L[i]


def igroups(L):
    return [[L[I[0]-1]]+[L[i] for i in I] for I in [I for (v,I) in [(k,[i for i in list(g)]) for (k, g) in groupby(range(1, len(L)), f)] if v]]
```

outputting:

```
tests=[
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5],
    [4,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,4,3],
    [1, 4, 3],
    [1],
    [1,2, 2],
    [2,1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 8],
    ]
for L in tests:
    print(L)
    print(igroups(L))
    print('-'*10)


[0, 0, 0, 0]
[]
----------
[7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[[7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
----------
[8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[[8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
----------
[9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
----------
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
----------
[1, 4, 3]
[]
----------
[1]
[]
----------
[1, 2, 2]
[[1, 2]]
----------
[2, 1]
[]
----------
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 8]
[]
----------
```

Some explanation. If you "unroll" the code, the logic is more apparant :

```
from itertools import groupby

def f(i):
    return L[i]==L[i-1]+1

def igroups(L):
    monotonic_states = [(k,list(g)) for (k, g) in groupby(range(1, len(L)), f)]
    increasing_items_indices = [I for (v,I) in monotonic_states if v]
    print("\nincreasing_items_indices ->", increasing_items_indices, '\n')
    full_increasing_items= [[L[I[0]-1]]+[L[i] for i in I] for I in increasing_items_indices]
    return full_increasing_items

L= [2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 25, 26, 27, 42, 41]
print(L)
print(igroups(L))
```

outputting :

```
[2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 9, 10, 11, 12, 25, 26, 27, 42, 41]

increasing_items_indices -> [[3, 4, 5, 6], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14]]

[[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [25, 26, 27]]
```

We need a key function `f` that compares an item with the preceding one in the given list. Now, the important point is that the `groupby` function with the key function `f` provides a tuple `(k, S)` where S represents *adjacent* indices from the initial list and where the state of `f` is constant, the state being given by the value of `k`: if  `k` is `True`, then `S` represents increasing (by 1) items indices else non-increasing items indices. (in fact, as the example above shows, the list S is incomplete and lacks the first item).

I also made some random tests with one million items lists : `igroups` function returns always the correct response but is 4 times slower than a naive implementation! Simpler is easier and faster ;)

Thanks alvas for your question, it gives me a lot of fun!

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for unrolling the list comprehensions and explaning it.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `L[i]>L[i-1]` instead of `L[i] == L[i]+1`?

Comment: @alvas: I suppose you are talking about the definition of the key function, don't you? But how `L[i] == L[i]+1` is possible ?

Comment: Ah i see what you're doing, you're also keeping the increasing but not +1 sequences!! Kool!!!

Comment: @P.Ortiz. The OP has said in other comments that the sequences should only increase by one. So perhaps they meant `L[i] == L[i-1]+1`? (PS: what is a "naive" implementation?)

Comment: @P.Ortiz, One issue though, groupby seem to do some sorting which sorts the order of the sequences.

Comment: @alvas. I don't think so. BTW, at first time, I missed you need **consecutive** increasing sub-sequences. I update my codes.

Comment: @ ekhumoro By naive implementation I mean the basic one you write if you are not aware of itertools and even iterator, the one a beginner is going to write.  You need only a `for` loop, `if`/`else` conditions,  list creation and the `append` method to populate the list with consecutive items. More or less, the implementation you will write with a low level language like C.

Comment: @P.Ortiz. I always thought "naive" meant a crude solution that missed most of the edge cases. Or to put it another way: it's the sort of solution most people get if they don't do any testing :-)

Answer (score 0):

A (really) simple implementation:

```
x = [7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = []
current = x[0]
temp = []
for i in xrange(1, len(x)):
    if (x[i] - current == 1):
        temp.append( x[i] )
    else:
         if (len(temp) > 1):
             result.append(temp)
         temp = [ x[i] ]
    current = x[i]
result.append(temp)
```

And you will get `[ [7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ]`. From there, you can get the number of increasing numbers by `[ len(x) for x in result ]` and the total number of numbers `sum( len(x) for x in result)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works.  It's not fancy but it's simple.  It constructs a start list `sl` and an end list `el`, which should always be the same length, then uses them to index into `x`:

```
def igroups(x):
    sl = [i for i in range(len(x)-1)
          if (x == 0 or x[i] != x[i-1]+1) and x[i+1] == x[i]+1]

    el = [i for i in range(1, len(x))
          if x[i] == x[i-1]+1 and (i == len(x)-1 or x[i+1] != x[i]+1)]

    return [x[sl[i]:el[i]+1] for i in range(len(sl))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but a simple implementation, generalized to take a predicate so that it need not necessarily be increasing numbers, but could readily be any relationship between the two numbers.

```py
def group_by(lst, predicate):
    result = [[lst[0]]]
    for i, x in enumerate(lst[1:], start=1):
        if not predicate(lst[i - 1], x):
            result.append([x])
        else:
            result[-1].append(x)
    return list(filter(lambda lst: len(lst) > 1, result))
```

Testing this:

```
>>> group_by([1,2,3,4, 7, 1, 0, 2], lambda x, y: x < y)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 7], [0, 2]]
>>> group_by([1,2,3,4, 7, 1, 0, 2], lambda x, y: x > y)
[[7, 1, 0]]
>>> group_by([1,2,3,4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 2], lambda x, y: x < y)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 7], [0, 2]]
>>> group_by([1,2,3,4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 2], lambda x, y: x > y)
[[7, 1, 0]]
>>> group_by([1,2,3,4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 2], lambda x, y: x >= y)
[[7, 1, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

And now we can easily specialize this:

```
>>> def ascending_groups(lst):
...     return group_by(lst, lambda x, y: x < y)
... 
>>> ascending_groups([1,2,3,4, 7, 1, 0, 0, 2])
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 7], [0, 2]]
>>>
```