# Grouping numbers in a list of floats in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of floats in random number like this:

```
float_list=[7.1, 7.1, 8.3, 8.5, 6.7,6.8, 6.9, 4.0, 4.2, 9.0]
```

I want to organize the list with tuples as below:

```
float_list=[(7.1, 7.1, 8.3, 8.5), (6.7, 6.8,6.9), (4.0, 4.2, 9.0)]
```

I tried using group_by method from itertools but could not get the expected results. I have indedd see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402355/finding-groups-of-increasing-numbers-in-a-list) solution but this is not what i'm asking,I have float with varying deltas.

Comment: Under what logic will the grouping be done?

Comment: @IoaTzimas group until the number just after is smaller than the number